# Programmatically triggering the privileges dialog under a Lazarus application on Ubuntu

Tags: freepascal, lazarus, privilege-elevation

I want to ease my father's task of installing some software that I'm developing for him.
For this I'm using Lazarus and I would like to know if there is and API to raize the privilege escalation dialog.

It seams to be hard to pin-point a single query to present on Google:
["lazarus privilege escalation"](http://www.google.com/search?q=lazarus+privilege+escalation) is not helping.
["lazarus privilege dialog"](http://www.google.com/search?q=lazarus+privilege+dialog) is not helping either.

I do realize that it's possible to ask the user to run it under `gksudo`, but I would like to avoid any scripting or command line using.

So I'm a bit lost in terms of where to turn.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TProcess to run some tasks with privileges you need using sudo (maybe gksudo works too).
Here you have example how to do it:

http://wiki.freepascal.org/Executing_External_Programs#Redirecting_input_and_output_and_running_under_root

Comment: My original idea is to raise the running program's privileges, so it can run internal routines as an elevated user, not external commands.

Comment: Did you try to run your program itself as root with method above and then terminate the first instance?